# How does matlab lognfit work?

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

Does lognfit bin the data before fitting?
If so, how does it determine the number of bins, the bin width, and pick the binned data points that get fitted?
If not, how does it do the fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general strategy to reverse engineer the algorithm is to use look at the `.m` files associated with these functions.

Perhaps I'm misreading the comments but I think it does a least-squares fit without binning. You can fit a guassian without binning right?

For example, `lognfit.m` appears to be a fancy wrapper for `normfit.m`

```
function [parmhat, parmci] = lognfit(x,alpha,censoring,freq,options)
%LOGNFIT Parameter estimates and confidence intervals for lognormal data.
%   PARMHAT = LOGNFIT(X) returns a vector of maximum likelihood estimates 
%   PARMHAT(1) = MU and PARMHAT(2) = SIGMA of parameters for a lognormal 
%   distribution fitting X.  MU and SIGMA are the mean and standard 
%   deviation, respectively, of the associated normal distribution.
%
%   [PARMHAT,PARMCI] = LOGNFIT(X) returns 95% confidence intervals for the
%   parameter estimates.
%
%   [PARMHAT,PARMCI] = LOGNFIT(X,ALPHA) returns 100(1-ALPHA) percent
%   confidence intervals for the parameter estimates.
%
%   [...] = LOGNFIT(X,ALPHA,CENSORING) accepts a boolean vector of the same
%   size as X that is 1 for observations that are right-censored and 0 for
%   observations that are observed exactly.
%
%   [...] = LOGNFIT(X,ALPHA,CENSORING,FREQ) accepts a frequency vector of
%   the same size as X.  FREQ typically contains integer frequencies for
%   the corresponding elements in X, but may contain any non-integer
%   non-negative values.
%
%   [...] = LOGNFIT(X,ALPHA,CENSORING,FREQ,OPTIONS) specifies control
%   parameters for the iterative algorithm used to compute ML estimates
%   when there is censoring.  This argument can be created by a call to
%   STATSET.  See STATSET('lognfit') for parameter names and default values.
%
%   Pass in [] for ALPHA, CENSORING, or FREQ to use their default values.
%
%   With no censoring, SIGMAHAT is the square root of the unbiased estimate
%   of the variance of log(X).  With censoring, SIGMAHAT is the maximum
%   likelihood estimate.
%
%   See also LOGNCDF, LOGNINV, LOGNLIKE, LOGNPDF, LOGNRND, LOGNSTAT, MLE,
%            STATSET.

%   References:
%      [1] Evans, M., Hastings, N., and Peacock, B. (1993) Statistical
%          Distributions, 2nd ed., Wiley, 170pp.
%      [2] Lawless, J.F. (1982) Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime
%          Data, Wiley, New York, 580pp.
%      [3} Meeker, W.Q. and L.A. Escobar (1998) Statistical Methods for
%          Reliability Data, Wiley, New York, 680pp.

%   Copyright 1993-2011 The MathWorks, Inc.


% Illegal data return an error.
if ~isvector(x)
    error(message('stats:lognfit:VectorRequired'));
elseif any(x <= 0)
    error(message('stats:lognfit:PositiveDataRequired'));
end

if nargin < 2 || isempty(alpha)
    alpha = 0.05;
end
if nargin < 3 || isempty(censoring)
    censoring = [];
elseif ~isempty(censoring) && ~isequal(size(x), size(censoring))
    error(message('stats:lognfit:InputSizeMismatchCensoring'));
end
if nargin < 4 || isempty(freq)
    freq = [];
elseif ~isempty(freq) && ~isequal(size(x), size(freq))
    error(message('stats:lognfit:InputSizeMismatchFreq'));
end
if nargin < 5 || isempty(options)
    options = [];
end

% Fit a normal distribution to the logged data.  The parameterizations of
% the normal and lognormal are identical.
%
% Get parameter estimates only.
if nargout <= 1
    [muhat,sigmahat] = normfit(log(x),alpha,censoring,freq,options);
    parmhat = [muhat sigmahat];

% Get parameter estimates and CIs.
else
    [muhat,sigmahat,muci,sigmaci] = normfit(log(x),alpha,censoring,freq,options);
    parmhat = [muhat sigmahat];
    parmci = [muci sigmaci];
end
```

Also for reference `normfit.m`

```
function [muhat, sigmahat, muci, sigmaci] = normfit(x,alpha,censoring,freq,options)
%NORMFIT Parameter estimates and confidence intervals for normal data.
%   [MUHAT,SIGMAHAT] = NORMFIT(X) returns estimates of the parameters of
%   the normal distribution given the data in X.  MUHAT is an estimate of
%   the mean, and SIGMAHAT is an estimate of the standard deviation.
%
%   [MUHAT,SIGMAHAT,MUCI,SIGMACI] = NORMFIT(X) returns 95% confidence
%   intervals for the parameter estimates.
%
%   [MUHAT,SIGMAHAT,MUCI,SIGMACI] = NORMFIT(X,ALPHA) returns 100(1-ALPHA)
%   percent confidence intervals for the parameter estimates.
%
%   [...] = NORMFIT(X,ALPHA,CENSORING) accepts a boolean vector of the same
%   size as X that is 1 for observations that are right-censored and 0 for
%   observations that are observed exactly.
%
%   [...] = NORMFIT(X,ALPHA,CENSORING,FREQ) accepts a frequency vector of the
%   same size as X.  FREQ typically contains integer frequencies for the
%   corresponding elements in X, but may contain any non-integer
%   non-negative values.
%
%   [...] = NORMFIT(X,ALPHA,CENSORING,FREQ,OPTIONS) specifies control
%   parameters for the iterative algorithm used to compute ML estimates
%   when there is censoring.  This argument can be created by a call to
%   STATSET.  See STATSET('normfit') for parameter names and default values.
%
%   Pass in [] for ALPHA, CENSORING, or FREQ to use their default values.
%
%   With no censoring, SIGMAHAT is computed using the square root of the
%   unbiased estimator of the variance.  With censoring, SIGMAHAT is the
%   maximum likelihood estimate.
%
%   See also NORMCDF, NORMINV, NORMLIKE, NORMPDF, NORMRND, NORMSTAT, MLE, STATSET.

%   References:
%      [1] Evans, M., Hastings, N., and Peacock, B. (1993) Statistical
%          Distributions, 2nd ed., Wiley, 170pp.
%      [2] Lawless, J.F. (1982) Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime
%          Data, Wiley, New York, 580pp.
%      [3} Meeker, W.Q. and L.A. Escobar (1998) Statistical Methods for
%          Reliability Data, Wiley, New York, 680pp.

%   To compute weighted maximum likelihood estimates (WMLEs) for mu and
%   sigma, you can provide weights, normalized to sum to LENGTH(X), in FREQ
%   instead of frequencies.  In this case, NORMFIT computes the WMLE for
%   mu.  However, when there is no censoring, the estimate computed for
%   sigma is not exactly the WMLE.  To compute the WMLE, multiply the value
%   returned in SIGMAHAT by (SUM(FREQ) - 1)/SUM(FREQ).  This correction is
%   needed because NORMFIT normally computes SIGMAHAT using an unbiased
%   variance estimator when there is no censoring in the data.  When there
%   is censoring, the correction is not needed, since NORMFIT does not use
%   the unbiased variance estimator in that case.

%   Copyright 1993-2015 The MathWorks, Inc.


% Illegal data return an error.
if ~isvector(x)
    if nargin < 3
        % Accept matrix data under the 2-arg syntax.  censoring and freq
        % will be scalar zero and one.
        [n,ncols] = size(x); % all columns have same number of data
    else
        error(message('stats:normfit:InvalidData'));
    end
else
    n = numel(x); % a scalar -- all columns have same number of data
    ncols = 1;
end

if nargin < 2 || isempty(alpha)
    alpha = 0.05;
end
if nargin < 3 || isempty(censoring)
    censoring = 0; % make this a scalar, will expand when needed
elseif ~isempty(censoring) && ~isequal(size(x), size(censoring))
    error(message('stats:normfit:InputSizeMismatchCensoring'));
end
if nargin < 4 || isempty(freq)
    freq = 1; % make this a scalar, will expand when needed
elseif isequal(size(x), size(freq))
    n = sum(freq);
    zerowgts = find(freq == 0);
    if numel(zerowgts) > 0
        x(zerowgts) = [];
        if numel(censoring)==numel(freq), censoring(zerowgts) = []; end
        freq(zerowgts) = [];
    end
else
    error(message('stats:normfit:InputSizeMismatchFreq'));
end
if nargin < 5 || isempty(options)
    options = [];
end

ncen = sum(freq.*censoring); % a scalar in all cases
nunc = n - ncen; % a scalar in all cases
sumx = sum(freq.*x);

% Weed out cases which cannot really be fit, no data or all censored.  When
% all observations are censored, the likelihood surface is at its maximum
% (zero) for any mu > max(x) at the boundary sigma==0.
if n == 0 || nunc == 0
    muhat = NaN(1,ncols,'like',x);
    sigmahat = NaN(1,ncols,'like',x);
    muci = NaN(2,ncols,'like',x);
    sigmaci = NaN(2,ncols,'like',x);
    return

% No censoring, find the parameter estimates explicitly.
elseif ncen == 0
    muhat = sumx ./ n;
    if n > 1
        if numel(muhat) == 1 % vector data
            xc = x - muhat;
        else % matrix data
            xc = x - repmat(muhat,[n 1]);
        end
        sigmahat = sqrt(sum(conj(xc).*xc.*freq) ./ (n-1));
    else
        sigmahat = zeros(1,ncols,'like',x);
    end

    if nargout > 2
        if n > 1
            parmhat = [muhat; sigmahat];
            ci = statnormci(parmhat,[],alpha,x,[],freq);
            muci = ci(:,:,1);
            sigmaci = ci(:,:,2);
        else
            muci = [-Inf; Inf]*ones(1,ncols,'like',x);
            sigmaci = [0; Inf]*ones(1,ncols,'like',x);
        end
    end
    return
end
% Past this point, guaranteed to have only one vector of data, with censoring.

% Not much can be done with Infs, either censored or uncensored.
if ~isfinite(sumx)
    muhat = sumx;
    sigmahat = NaN('like',x);
    muci = NaN(2,1,'like',x);
    sigmaci = NaN(2,1,'like',x);
    return
end

% When all uncensored observations are equal and greater than all the
% censored observations, the likelihood surface becomes infinite at the
% boundary sigma==0.  Return something reasonable anyway.
xunc = x(censoring==0);
rangexUnc = range(xunc);
if rangexUnc < realmin(internal.stats.typeof(x))
    if xunc(1) == max(x)
        muhat = xunc(1);
        sigmahat = zeros('like',x);
        if nunc > 1
            muci = [muhat; muhat];
            sigmaci = zeros(2,1,'like',x);
        else
            muci = cast([-Inf; Inf],'like',x);
            sigmaci = cast([0; Inf],'like', x);
        end
        return
    end
end
% Otherwise the data are ok to fit, go on.

% First, get a rough estimate for parameters using the "least squares" method
% as a starting value...
if rangexUnc > 0
    if numel(freq) == numel(x)
        [p,q] = ecdf(x, 'censoring',censoring, 'frequency',freq);
    else
        [p,q] = ecdf(x, 'censoring',censoring);
    end
    pmid = (p(1:(end-1))+p(2:end)) / 2;
    linefit = polyfit(-sqrt(2)*erfcinv(2*pmid), q(2:end), 1);
    parmhat = linefit([2 1]);

% ...unless there's only one uncensored value.
else
    parmhat = [xunc(1) 1];
end

% Optimize the parameters as doubles, regardless of input data type
parmhat = cast(parmhat,'like',1);

% The default options include turning statsfminbx's display off.  This
% function gives its own warning/error messages, and the caller can
% turn display on to get the text output from statsfminbx if desired.
options = statset(statset('normfit'), options);
tolBnd = options.TolBnd;
options = optimset(options);
dfltOptions = struct('DerivativeCheck','off', 'HessMult',[], ...
    'HessPattern',ones(2,2), 'PrecondBandWidth',Inf, ...
    'TypicalX',ones(2,1), 'MaxPCGIter',1, 'TolPCG',0.1);

% Maximize the log-likelihood with respect to mu and sigma.
funfcn = {'fungrad' 'normfit' @negloglike [] []};
[parmhat, ~, ~, err, output] = ...
         statsfminbx(funfcn, parmhat, [-Inf; tolBnd], [Inf; Inf], ...
                     options, dfltOptions, 1, x, censoring, freq);
if (err == 0)
    % statsfminbx may print its own output text; in any case give something
    % more statistical here, controllable via warning IDs.
    if output.funcCount >= options.MaxFunEvals
        warning(message('stats:normfit:EvalLimit'));
    else
        warning(message('stats:normfit:IterLimit'));
    end
elseif (err < 0)
    error(message('stats:normfit:NoSolution'));
end

% Make sure the outputs match the input data type
muhat = cast(parmhat(1),'like',x);
sigmahat = cast(parmhat(2),'like',x);

if nargout > 2
    parmhat = parmhat(:);
    if numel(freq) == numel(x)
        [~, acov] = normlike(parmhat, x, censoring, freq);
    else
        [~, acov] = normlike(parmhat, x, censoring);
    end
    ci = statnormci(parmhat,acov,alpha,x,censoring,freq);
    muci = ci(:,:,1);
    sigmaci = ci(:,:,2);
end


function [nll,ngrad] = negloglike(parms, x, censoring, freq)
% (Negative) log-likelihood function and gradient for normal distribution.
%
% Note that both outputs are the same type as the PARMS input
mu = parms(1);
sigma = parms(2);
cens = (censoring == 1);

z = (x - mu) ./ sigma;
zcen = z(cens);

Scen = .5*erfc(zcen/sqrt(2));
classX = internal.stats.typeof(x);
if all(Scen < realmin(classX))
    nll = cast(realmax(classX),'like',parms);
    ngrad = [nll nll];
    return
end
L = -.5.*z.*z - log(sigma);
L(cens) = log(Scen);
nll = -sum(freq .* L);
nll = cast(nll,'like',parms);

if nargout > 1
    dlogScen = exp(-.5*zcen.*zcen) ./ (sqrt(2*pi) .* Scen);
    dL1 = z ./ sigma;
    dL1(cens) = dlogScen ./ sigma;
    dL2 = (z.*z - 1) ./ sigma;
    dL2(cens) = zcen .* dlogScen ./ sigma;
    ngrad = cast([-sum(freq .* dL1) -sum(freq .* dL2)],'like',parms);
end
```

Comment: Mikhail, you're posting copyrighted code in your answer - it even has a copyright line right there for you to see. Take it down, and edit your answer to just refer to the functions in question, along with line numbers if necessary.